# Extrapolate Coordinates form Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, selenium-chromedriver

I'm planning a climbing trip and I wanted to retrieve the climbing locations from a leaflet map.

I thought I could use chromedriver and selenium to get the information I wanted but I'm having difficulty scanning through all markers since I can't understand where all the informations are stored.

Could someone guide me through how I could get the information? (also without using selenium)

The map in question is: https://www.climbingsardinia.com/topos/maps/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that page you will see a global variable called cttm_markers, it contains all markers informations and relative coordinates.

For example, `cttm_markers[0][[0].additionalData.title` evaluates "M.te Arci – Trebina Longa".Further, `cttm_markers[0][[0]._latlng` is an object {lat,lng} that contains coordinates.

Try to open console and paste this: `JSON.stringify(cttm_markers[0].map(c=>({title:c.additionalData.title,latlng:c._latlng})))`, it will print a json.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to get some information on one of the markers and use this to search the request reponses made by the page (you can do this in the debug tools, usually opened with F12). One of the markers for example reveals the location "Grighini". The base request redirects to (in my case) https://www.climbingsardinia.com/topos/maps/?doing_wp_cron=1651158093.0027918815612792968750
Searching the response, reveals that in line 1908 there's the string "Grighini". This line contains a serialized JSON array, containing the markers.